# Lookups from two tables

Tags: axapta, x++

I need to create a lookup on Invoice account in Sales table. 
In the lookup I need to include the invoice account and the address table fields.

How do I acheive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on [Axaptapedia](http://axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=Lookups). There are other goodies there.

Two tables will require either the use of display methods or the use of inner or outer joins.